# Convert DataFrame with url in string format to JSON properly

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with 2 columns, one of which consists of URLs.

Sample code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('name', 'image'))
df = df.append({'name': 'sample_name', 'image': 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/736230/pexels-photo-736230.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500'}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'name': 'sample_name2', 'image': 'https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/mt/2017/10/Pict1_Ursinia_calendulifolia/lead_720_405.jpg?mod=1533691909'}, ignore_index=True)
```

I want to convert this dataframe to JSON directly. I've used `to_json()` method of DataFrame to convert, but when I do it, it kind of messes up the urls in the data frame.

Conversion to JSON:

```
json = df.to_json(orient='records')
```

When I print it, the conversion inserts '\' character to beginning of every '/' character in my url.

```
print(json)
```

Result:

```
[{"name":"sample_name","image":"https:\/\/images.pexels.com\/photos\/736230\/pexels-photo-736230.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"},{"na
me":"sample_name2","image":"https:\/\/cdn.theatlantic.com\/assets\/media\/img\/mt\/2017\/10\/Pict1_Ursinia_calendulifolia\/lead_720_405.jpg?mod=15
33691909"}]
```

I want the json to look like (no extra '\' in urls):

```
[{"name":"sample_name","image":"https://images.pexels.com/photos/736230/pexels-photo-736230.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"},{"na
    me":"sample_name2","image":"https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/mt/2017/10/Pict1_Ursinia_calendulifolia/lead_720_405.jpg?mod=15
    33691909"}]
```

I checked documentation of `to_json()` and other questions as well but couldn't find an answer to deal with it. How can I just convert my url strings to json, as they are in data frame?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pandas uses [**`ujson`** <sup>[PiPy]</sup>](https://pypi.org/project/ujson/) internally to encode the data to a JSON blob. `ujson` by default escapes slashes with the [**`escape_forward_slashes`**](https://pypi.org/project/ujson/#escape-forward-slashes) option.

You can just `json.dumps(…)` the result of converting your dataframe to a dictionary with `.to_dict`:

```
>>> import json
>>> print(json.dumps(df.to_dict('records')))
[{"name": "sample_name", "image": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/736230/pexels-photo-736230.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"}, {"name": "sample_name2", "image": "https://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/mt/2017/10/Pict1_Ursinia_calendulifolia/lead_720_405.jpg?mod=1533691909"}]
```